# working in different directories (os.chdir) in the same time (parallel threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, directory, multiprocessing

I want to sync all of my vcs directories in parallel. I'm going to directory and run special command line scripts to sync git or mercurial repositories. It's slow process so I want to try to make it parallel.

But there is trouble my parallel threads fight for "current directory" so I need some trick to work in different directories in the same time.

Current solution:

```
def syncrepos(repos):
  for r in repos.split("\n"):
    if r:
      print("------ repository: ", r)
      thrd = ThreadingSync(r)
      thrd.setDaemon(True)
      thrd.start()
```

where ThreadingSync is

```
class ThreadingSync(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, repo):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.repo = repo
  def run(self):
    r = self.repo.split("-t")
    path = (r[0]).strip()
    if len(r) < 2:
      vcs = VCS.git
    else:
      vcs = {
    'git'       : VCS.git,
    'git git'   : VCS.git_git,
    'git hg'    : VCS.git_mercurial,
    'git svn'   : VCS.git_subversion,
    'git vv'    : VCS.git_veracity,
    'hg hg'     : VCS.hg_hg}[(r[1]).strip()]
    os.chdir(path)
    if vcs == VCS.git:
      checkGitModifications()
      gitSync()
    ... etc
```

and `gitSync` is

```
def gitSync(): 
  pretty(cmd("git pull origin master"))
  pretty(cmd("git fetch upstream master"))
  pretty(cmd("git pull --rebase upstream master"))
  pretty(cmd("git push -f origin master"))
```

Sure this is not perfect but it does my work and I want to speed up it.

How to spawn one subprocess for each repository/directory (Thrad safe implementation of os.chdir) ?

Comment: What's the question? Your code is fairly opaque. Best I can suggest so far is (a) consider the multiprocessing module rather than the threading module - it might be easier to get started with, and (b) spawn one subprocess for each repository/directory, that way you don't have to worry about them tripping over each other.

Comment: @John Mee "spawn one subprocess for each repository/directory" - that is what I need and that is what the question is all about. How to do it?

Comment: @John Mee os.chdir(path) is in my Threading class but it's still being affecting other processes, thought os.chrdir affect some global variable, but how to deal with it?

Comment: Are you saying when you change directory in the subprocess, the current directory changes in all the subprocesses?  Interesting :-) Full paths then?

Comment: Full paths will not work sane though... I need thread-safe os.chdir alternative... I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a pool of workers to run your subroutine:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

In your case perhaps something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def gitSync(repo):
    print "I am", repo, "and my cwd is:", os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(repo)
    print "I am", repo, "and my cwd is:", os.getcwd()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir = os.getcwd()
    repos = [item for item in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, item))]
    print repos
    pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
    pool.map(gitSync, repos)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note that the pool can make debugging a bit difficult as the parent usually doesn't reveal much more than -one of my children died-, so get it working single threaded first.

Edit:
Well that was interesting to appreciate - note the new argument to the Pool `maxtasksperchild=1`. The process is not `rebooted` between invocations so when you change the directory in one invocation, you're still in that directory when the process gets reused.  Here I've solved it simply by telling the pool to kill processes after every single invocation.

```
john:captcrunch john$ python foo.py 
['.git', '.idea', 'fixtures', 'lib', 'obj', 'raw', 'tests']
I am .git and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am .git and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/.git
I am .idea and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am .idea and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/.idea
I am fixtures and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am fixtures and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/fixtures
I am lib and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am lib and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/lib
I am obj and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am obj and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/obj
I am raw and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am raw and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/raw
I am tests and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch
I am tests and my cwd is: /Users/john/code/linz/src/captcrunch/tests
```

Comment: How that will solve my trouble? e.g.: Will it make os.chdir thread-safe?

Comment: sorry we're cross posting comments now; my bad... see my question under the question.

Comment: with maxtasksperchild=1 is it really parallel?

Comment: Yep. Each core will be running separate processes simultaneously, it just specifies that you don't mind the overhead of creating a new one on every invocation. Try it on a decent sized set. You'll see all cores get used. I've never reached I/O saturation yet (i7 with an SSD admittedly).